# how to use git log and grep together?

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu

I am trying to use git log and grep together with pipe. However, it doesn't seem to work. I am grepping for the bug-id from the git log. Here is what I am doing.

```
$git log | grep -ir "BUG-1024"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `git log --grep "BUG-1024"`

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about that. Did some googling and found a well written tutorial by Atlassian about filtering the git log: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log/filtering-the-commit-history/

Comment: git is very powerful :D